# Question mark as duplicate but reference question show 404 error page

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I came across one [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/how-to-display-category-and-sub-category-with-check-box-by-customizing-catalin-s) which is marked as duplicate. So I try to open link of question provided but its shows 404 error page.

In this case How I can find solution provided?

Answer (score 1):

Here what happened.

The author asked two identical questions. This happens sometimes for different reasons. Apparently one of the questions was closed as duplicate. Then the other copy of the question was closed dues to some valid reason and after some time passed was automatically purged. That's how you get 404 page.

I also deleted the question you linked in your .. question to avoid further confusion.

Comment: What if the other copy of the question has correct solution but that question deleted by user or user account deleted by any reason, in that case what will happen?

Comment: Both versions had no answers.